# Generalization involving converse of Pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We all know the proof of the converse of the Pythagorean theorem.

*Quick remainder:
Suppose there exists a nonright triangle $ABC$ with sides $a, b, c$ which satisfy the well known relation, $c^2 = a^2 + b^2.$ Obviously there exists right triangle which also satisy this (because you can always construct a triangle with 2 sides you want and with angle you want between them): so construct right triangle with sides $a, b$ and let the third side be $c_1.$ Now, we have $a^2 + b^2 = c_1^2.$ Of course, then $c = c_1.$ By $SSS$ theorem this triangles are congruent and therefore $ABC$ have angle of $90°.$*

For me this proof is, although elementary, somewhat very promising.

**Now, my question:**

Let $ABC$ be some fixed triangle with sides $a, b, c$ as usual. Obviously $ABC$ have fixed angles $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma).$

Denote by $K$ set of all triangles which have (at least) one angle  same as $ABC$ (WLOG $\alpha$) and they have 1 *special* thing in common (please note that second condition tells us that having $\alpha$ as common "thing" is not enough).

$f(a, b) = c$ where $f(a, b)$ takes inputs $a, b$ and give output $c$ which is given by some fixed rule. For example, $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}, c = 1.0001(a + b), c = a^{\pi}b^e.$

Only pattern of this game of rules is that you can undo every possible rule that can satisfy elements of $K$ in a simillar way we did before $(c^2 = c_1^2 \implies c = c_1).$

Now suppose there exist triangle $XYZ \not\in K$ which satisfy fixed rule $f.$ Prove that this cannot be true. In ither words, it must be $XYZ \in K$ (by $SSS$?)

Comment: It follows from the cosine rule
\begin{eqnarray*}
c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos(C)
\end{eqnarray*}
and the observation that $\cos(C)=0$ implies that $C=90^{\circ}$.

Comment: Please, be more detailed. Notice that this is very general problem I posted; $\alpha, a, b$ and $f$ can be almost *anything*...

Comment: $f(a+b)$? Maybe you mean $f(a,b)$, Otherwise I don't get $c=a^{\pi}b^e$

Comment: Yes, I will change that...